# How do I set an input's value separately from the ngModel in Ionic 3 with Angular 4

Tags: angular, ionic3

I have a directive I'm creating for a currency input in an ionic 3 app. What I basically want is an input that says $11.11 but sets the ngModel value as 11.11.

My model value is setting correctly and my formatted string value is correct, but I can't get my input to display the formatted value.  Actually, my input displays whatever I type, letters and punctuation included, but all logged values are correct.  Does anyone know what I'm missing or a better way to go about what I'm trying to achieve?

**Example**
text typed into input: 1111
ngModel value: 11.11
console.log input value: $11.11
Actual input value: 1111 (should be $11.11)

```
import {Directive, Attribute, Output, EventEmitter, ElementRef, Renderer2} from '@angular/core';
import { NgModel } from '@angular/forms';
import {CurrencyPipe} from "@angular/common";

/**
 * Generated class for the CurrencyInputDirective directive.
 *
 * See https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/DirectiveMetadata-class.html
 * for more info on Angular Directives.
 */
@Directive({
  selector: '[currency-input]',
  providers: [NgModel]
})
export class CurrencyInputDirective {

  maximumAmount: number;
  currencyCode: string;
  decimals: number;
  modelValue: number;

  @Output() ciExceededMax: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

  constructor(public model: NgModel,
              public elementRef: ElementRef,
              private currencyPipe: CurrencyPipe,
              private renderer: Renderer2,
              @Attribute("ci-maximum-amount") maximumAmount: number,
              @Attribute("ci-currency-code") currencyCode: string,
              @Attribute("ci-decimals") decimals: number) {

    this.maximumAmount = (maximumAmount) ? maximumAmount : 10000;
    this.currencyCode = (currencyCode) ? currencyCode: 'USD';
    this.decimals = (decimals) ? Math.trunc(decimals) : 2;

    let directive = this;
    this.model.valueChanges.subscribe(function (value) {
      directive.modelValue = directive.getModelValue(value);
      directive.model.viewToModelUpdate(directive.modelValue);
      directive.writeValueToInput(directive.getFormattedModelValue(directive.modelValue));
    });

  }

  writeValueToInput(value) {

    //this.elementRef.nativeElement.value = value;
    this.renderer.setProperty(this.elementRef.nativeElement, 'value', value);

    console.log("element ref value " + this.elementRef.nativeElement.value);
    console.log("element ref " + JSON.stringify(this.elementRef.nativeElement, undefined, 2));
  }

  getFormattedModelValue(value) {
    let currencyDecimals = '1.' + this.decimals + "-" + this.decimals;

    let retVal: string = (!value) ? null : this.currencyPipe.transform(value, this.currencyCode, true, currencyDecimals);
    return (retVal) ? retVal : this.currencyPipe.transform(0, this.currencyCode, true, currencyDecimals);
  }

  getModelValue(value) {

    if(!value)
      return 0;

    let strippedValue: string = value.replace(/[^0-9]/g,"");
    let parsedInt: number = parseInt(strippedValue);
    let calculatedAmount = (parsedInt / Math.pow(10, this.decimals));

    if(calculatedAmount > this.maximumAmount){
      calculatedAmount = this.modelValue;

      setTimeout( () => {
        this.ciExceededMax.emit({amount: calculatedAmount, maxAmount: this.maximumAmount});
      }, 1);
    }

    console.log("returning calculated amount " + calculatedAmount);

    return calculatedAmount;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it.  I needed to use the NgControl to write the input value.

```
import {Directive, Attribute, Output, EventEmitter} from '@angular/core';
import {NgModel, NgControl} from '@angular/forms';
import {CurrencyPipe} from "@angular/common";

/**
 * Generated class for the CurrencyInputDirective directive.
 *
 * See https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/DirectiveMetadata-class.html
 * for more info on Angular Directives.
 */
@Directive({
  selector: '[currency-input]',
  providers: [NgModel]
})
export class CurrencyInputDirective {

  maximumAmount: number;
  currencyCode: string;
  decimals: number;
  modelValue: number;

  @Output() ciExceededMax: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

  constructor(public model: NgModel,
              private control : NgControl,
              private currencyPipe: CurrencyPipe,
              @Attribute("ci-maximum-amount") maximumAmount: number,
              @Attribute("ci-currency-code") currencyCode: string,
              @Attribute("ci-decimals") decimals: number) {

    this.maximumAmount = (maximumAmount) ? maximumAmount : 10000;
    this.currencyCode = (currencyCode) ? currencyCode: 'USD';
    this.decimals = (decimals) ? Math.trunc(decimals) : 2;

    let directive = this;
    this.model.valueChanges.subscribe(function (value) {
      directive.modelValue = directive.getModelValue(value);
      directive.model.viewToModelUpdate(directive.modelValue);
      directive.control.valueAccessor.writeValue(directive.getFormattedModelValue(directive.modelValue));
    });

  }

  getFormattedModelValue(value) {
    let currencyDecimals = '1.' + this.decimals + "-" + this.decimals;

    let retVal: string = (!value) ? null : this.currencyPipe.transform(value, this.currencyCode, true, currencyDecimals);
    return (retVal) ? retVal : this.currencyPipe.transform(0, this.currencyCode, true, currencyDecimals);
  }

  getModelValue(value) {

    if(!value)
      return 0;

    let strippedValue: string = value.replace(/[^0-9]/g,"");
    let parsedInt: number = parseInt(strippedValue);
    let calculatedAmount = (parsedInt / Math.pow(10, this.decimals));

    if(calculatedAmount > this.maximumAmount){
      calculatedAmount = this.modelValue;

      setTimeout( () => {
        this.ciExceededMax.emit({amount: calculatedAmount, maxAmount: this.maximumAmount});
      }, 1);
    }

    return calculatedAmount;
  }

}
```